# black screen& touch-pad issue on 17.10

Tags: 17.10

i just installed ubuntu 17.10 on my laptop. only able to boot if set kernel parameter as "nomodeset" and even after boot to ubuntu 17.10 animations becomes very slow and again one problem with my ubuntu 17.10 is that touch-pad speed increase suddenly. please help me to fix this issue

Comment: It is best to ask only related question in one question. Please consider splitting your questions in to two. Adding details about your laptop will help get good answers faster.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem, and found a solution on my laptop.  This is a graphics problem, you might need to launch your system with ubuntu xorg which is an older desktop environment.  To do that lock your account,  and on the login screen where you have to type your password there is an option to choose your desktop environment.  It is "wayland" by default on ubuntu 17.10 which is a new desktop environment for ubuntu, choose "ubuntu xorg" instead and this might solve your problem.

Comment: Hi! my issue with 17.10 has been solved by updating BIOS! now no problem at all!